# How to open links from email clients like Thunderbird and N1 with custom configuration in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

What I want to do is that every time when I click on a link in Thunderbird or Nylas N1, depending on which email address the link contains, to open Firefox with a specific user profile.

I'm using Fedora 23, but I would like to be a solution that can be ported to other platforms as well.